# identifying users upon some action or disconnected

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, jwt

I'm new to node

I have a PHP/Laravel cms and I have a simple Nodejs game server which is basically a loop generating some numbers

I connect my PHP backend to Nodejs via Socketio and use `Socketio-JWT` to identify the user

my client side (php/laravel)

PHP

`$userToken = JWTAuth::customClaims(['userid' => Auth::user()->id, 'name' => Auth::user()->name, 'avatar' => asset_url('image/avatar-default.png')])->fromUser(Auth::user() );`

html/js

```
        var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:666");

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            socket.emit('authenticate', {token: '{{$userToken}}'});
        });
        socket.on('authenticated', function () {
            console.log('Authenticated');
        });
        socket.on('unauthorized', function (data) {
            console.log('Unauthorized, error msg: ' + data.message);
        });
```

my serverside

```
const _online_users = { };
io.sockets

    .on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
        secret:  JWT_SECRET,
        timeout: 15000
    }))

    .on('authenticated', function(socket) {

        _online_users[socket.decoded_token.userid] = {
            name : socket.decoded_token.name ,
            avatar : socket.decoded_token.avatar ,
        }

        io.sockets.emit('update_online_users' ,  _online_users  );
            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                 console.log(`----- @@disconnect -----`)
            });
    })  ;
```

as you can see I have an object called `_online_users` and I store authenticated users in this object and then I send it to the clients so they know who is online 
 `io.sockets.emit('update_online_users' ,  _online_users  );`

here is the problem, when the user gets disconnected

```
            socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                 console.log(`----- @@disconnect -----`)
            });
```

I have to update my `_online_users`  object and remove disconnected user .... how should I go about this? I was thinking maybe I can store the token itself in the `_online_users`

```
        _online_users[socket.decoded_token.userid] = {
           token  : socket.token ,
            name : socket.decoded_token.name ,
            avatar : socket.decoded_token.avatar ,
        }
```

and when the user gets disconnected I get the disconnected token from the socket and remove the user from an object by that  token

of course, this is all theory! I'm not sure if that's the way to go .... first of all, I can't access the token itself from the socket !

or let's say one of the users sends another request to node server, how can I identify the user sending the request?

```
    .on('authenticated', function(socket) {

            socket.on('somaction', function() {
                 console.log(` who is this guy ? `)
            });

    })
```

is there anything unique in`socket.decoded_token` that I can use as id?  if so I can store it in the online users send it back and forth when the user  requests something

basically I'm lost and appreciate any pointers

Comment: My English is bad to help you, but I have the same routine in my ad system. In my case, I used a collection on the redis server, but I don't immediately disconnect the user, I act on it and send a socket.emit several times for a certain period of time, if it doesn't respond to my ping. the collection of members of the redis server and deleted along with their connection data that is in another collection.

Comment: Could you give some feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing well!

Since you are adding `socket` event handlers in the `'authenticated'` handler you still have access to `socket.decoded_token.userid`.

This should be enough:

```
const _online_users = {};
io.sockets

    .on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
        secret:  JWT_SECRET,
        timeout: 15000
    }))

    .on('authenticated', function(socket) {

        _online_users[socket.decoded_token.userid] = {
            name:   socket.decoded_token.name,
            avatar: socket.decoded_token.avatar,
        };

        io.sockets.emit('update_online_users', _online_users);

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log(`----- @@disconnect -----`);

            delete _online_users[socket.decoded_token.userid];

            io.sockets.emit('update_online_users', _online_users);
        });
    });
```

or to be a little more concise:

```
const _online_users = {};
io.sockets

    .on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
        secret:  JWT_SECRET,
        timeout: 15000
    }))

    .on('authenticated', function(socket) {
        const { avatar, name, userid } = socket.decoded_token;

        _online_users[userid] = { name, avatar };
        io.sockets.emit('update_online_users', _online_users);

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            delete _online_users[userid];
            io.sockets.emit('update_online_users', _online_users);
        });

        socket.on('any other event...', function() {
            // ... still have access to userid
        });
    });
```

**Edit:** About unauthenticated socket I don't know; doc says nothing. You could try something like:

```
io.socket.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.emit('update_online_users', _online_users);

  // I'm afraid this closes the socket if unauthorized, you could check by yourself
  socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret:  JWT_SECRET,
    timeout: 15000
  })(socket);
}).on('authenticated', socket => {
  //...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx , yes it works so simple , i should have seen this : ))  .... im just trying middleware solution as well to see how that works

Comment: Sure, for learning purposes it's a good idea, but my suggestion is to not add code which is actually not required.

Comment: any idea how can i emit data to unauthorized users ? i mean they should get online users as well but since im using  `socketioJwt.authorize` as connect event callback i've only access to authenticated user socket

Answer (score 2):

You can use a middleware now in the newer versions of `socket-io`. So you can check if the user is logged in by the `jwt` token that is sent with the request. If decoded successfully you can assign the user info to the current socket and call `next()` and go to the event you are listening for. Here is the example provided in the socket-io docs slightly modified for your case.

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  const handshakeData = socket.request;
  // make sure the handshake data looks good as before
  // if error do this:
    // next(new Error('not authorized'));

  // else decode jwt token here and append the user to the socket.request
  // and call next
  // pseudo code here
  const {
         authorization
       } = handshakeData.header
  let token;

  if (authorization && authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer") {
        token = authorization.split(" ")[1]
    }
  let user = jwt.decode(token, secret);
  socket.request.user = user;
  next();
});
```